# How to display data from the nested object in Vue.js based on click event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array with 3 objects inside. Each object has 4 properties:

```
     buttons: [
      {
        id: 'btn1',
        name: 'button-1',
        number: 1,
        color: 'red'
      },
      {
        id: 'btn2',
        name: 'button-2',
        number: 2,
        color: 'blue'
      },
      {
        id: 'btn3',
        name: 'button-3',
        number: 3,
        color: 'orange'
      }
    ]
```

In my html I have 3 buttons, each one connected to the given object.

```
<button id="btn1" name="" number="" color="">One</button>
<button id="btn2" name="" number="" color="">Two</button>
<button id="btn3" name="" number="" color="">Two</button>

<hr>

<h2>Clicked button data:</h2>

<p>{{ id }}</p>
<p>{{ name }}</p>
<p>{{ number }}</p>
<p>{{ color }}</p>
```

How can I display data for the given object based on the clicked button?

Here is a snippet with my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/marektchas/rqjxpav2/1/

Comment: @vignesh already gave a nice answer, I was, in the meantime, updating your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n495t7bv/3/ - "unfortunately" he was faster ;)

Comment: Thank you. I have one more issue which complicates my problem. What if instead of buttons I have SVG map and each province works as a button that suppose to display a data about a clicked province? Here is my snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/marektchas/4jbzuv5x/4/

Comment: @MarekHas https://jsfiddle.net/8x14gcqs/1/

Comment: Great, thank you very much!

Comment: @Pradeepb could please provide some explanation to your code? It works fine, however I don't understand it entirely. For example how does it work that you use title attribute to bind it with the data object?

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty simple. You just need to attach an event listener with the `@` prefix. That listener must be a method defined in the `methods` object on your vue object. Then you can just let the method receive the button object as a parameter. In my example I added a current property that is set by the method and contains the last pressed button. I also replaced the four buttons with one input and a `v-for` directive but it also works with buttons.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    buttons: [{
        id: 'btn1',
        name: 'button-1',
        number: 1,
        color: 'red'
      },
      {
        id: 'btn2',
        name: 'button-2',
        number: 2,
        color: 'blue'
      },
      {
        id: 'btn3',
        name: 'button-3',
        number: 3,
        color: 'orange'
      }
    ],
    current: {}
  },
  methods: {
    setCurrent(btn) {
      this.current = btn;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="button" v-for="btn in buttons" :id="btn.id" @click="setCurrent(btn)" :value="btn.name">
  <p>{{ current.id }}</p>
  <p>{{ current.name }}</p>
  <p>{{ current.number }}</p>
  <p>{{ current.color }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest your solution to be the best answer

Answer (score 1):

For Button:

```
<button id="btn1" name="" number="" color="" @click="set_SelectedButton(1)">One</button>
```

in Methods:

```
set_SelectedButton(value){
// or Based on condition how every you want
this.btn_id="value"
}


<h2>Clicked button data:</h2>

<p>{{ button[btn_id].id }}</p>
<p>{{ button[btn_id].name }}</p>
<p>{{ button[btn_id].number }}</p>
<p>{{ button[btn_id].color }}</p>
```

Comment: What in the situation I have hundreds of buttons and I don't want to manually place @click event in every one of them but I just want to based on the ID to display other associated data? Or event worst - I don't know yes how many buttons will be rendered so I can't add any event to html?

Comment: so if the button is dynamic then you should be using Select element, and if you use the button in the table then you can find the button value with `scope.row.id` with a single method. Hope my explanation is convincing for the situation.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a function based on button number.

```
 <button id="btn1" name="" number="" color=""
   @click = "clickedOn(1)">One</button>
 <button id="btn2" name="" number="" color=""
   @click = "clickedOn(2)">Two</button>
 <button id="btn3" name="" number="" color=""
   @click = "clickedOn(3)">Three</button>

 <hr>
 <h2>Clicked button data:</h2>
 <p>{{ dataToShow.id }}</p>
 <p>{{ dataToShow.name }}</p>
 <p>{{ dataToShow.number }}</p>
 <p>{{ dataToShow.color }}</p>
</div>
```

You can check working example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/nud19tfz/

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    buttons: [
      {
        id: 'btn1',
        name: 'button-1',
        number: 1,
        color: 'red'
      },
      {
        id: 'btn2',
        name: 'button-2',
        number: 2,
        color: 'blue'
      },
      {
        id: 'btn3',
        name: 'button-3',
        number: 3,
        color: 'orange'
      }
    ],
    dataToShow: {}
  },
  methods: {
   clickedOn: function(btnNum) {
    this.dataToShow = this.buttons[btnNum-1]
   }
 }
});
```